# I made an upload script in PHP. How do I avoid overwriting files?

Tags: php

I've made an image upload script using the `move_uploaded_file` function. This function seems to overwrite any preexisting file with the new one. So, I need to check if the target location already has a file. If it does then I need to append something to the filename(before the extension so that the file name is still valid) so the filename is unique. I'd like to have the change be minimal instead of something like appending the datetime, if possible.

How can I do this with PHP?

Comment: Are you using the name the user named the file as the name on your server? That is dangerous.

Comment: Yes. Do you have any suggestions for sanitizing the name or would I be forced to make an arbitrary name myself, for security reasons?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When uploading files I will nearly always rename them. Typically there will be some kind of database record for that file. I use the ID of that to guarantee uniqueness of the file. Sometimes I'll even store what the client's original filename was in the database too but I'll never keep it or the temporary name because there is no guarantee that information is good, that your OS will support it or that it's unique (which is your issue).

So just rename it to some scheme of your own devising. That's my advice.

If you don't have any database reference, then you could use [file_exists()](http://au.php.net/file_exists) for this but there's no guarantee that between the time of checking if something exists and moving it that something else won't use that same filename that you'll then overwrite. This is a classic [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).

Comment: The downside of that solution is, that some people give meaningful names to their files, which get lost during a complete renaming…

Answer (score 2):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Answer (score 1):

Don't use file_exists() for the reason that it returns true (on *nix systems at least, since directories are specialized files) if the value is a directory. Use is_file() instead.

For example, say something fails and you have a string like:

```
$path = "/path/to/file/" . $file; // Assuming $file is an empty value, if something failed for example
if ( true === file_exists($path) ) { echo "This returns true"; }
if ( true === is_file($path) ) { echo "You will not read this"; }
```

It's caused a few problems in the past for me, so I always use is_file() rather than file_exists().

Answer (score 1):

I use date and time functions to generate a random file name based on the time of upload.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you are submitting a file from a form where you have an input named `incomingfile` like this:

```
<input type="file" id="incomingfile" name="incomingfile" />
```

First of all I use to "depure" the filename and copy it from the default temporary directory to a temporary directory. This is necessary to deal with special characters. I had troubles when I didn't adopt this practice.

```
$new_depured_filename = strtolower(preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ -.]/s', '_', $_FILES["incomingfile"]["name"]));
copy($_FILES["incomingfile"]["tmp_name"], 'my_temp_directory/'.$new_depured_filename);
```

With the following piece of code I check if the file exists, if so, I find a new name and finally copy it. For example if I want to write a file called `myimage.jpg` and it already exists I rename the pending file to `myimage__000.jpg`. If this exists as well I rename the pending file to myimage__001.jpg and so on until I find a non-existing filename.

```
$i=0; // A counter for the tail to append to the filename
$new_filename = $new_depured_filename;
$new_filepath='myfiles/music/'.$new_filename;
while(file_exists($new_filepath)) {
    $tail = str_pad((string) $i, 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT); // Converts the integer in $i to a     string of 3 characters with left zero fill.
    $fileinfos = pathinfo($new_filepath); // Gathers some infos about the file
    if($i>0) { // If we aren't at the first while cycle (where you have the filename without any added strings) then delete the tail (like "__000") from the filename to add another one later (otherwise you'd have filenames like myfile__000__001__002__003.jpg)
        $previous_tail = str_pad((string) $i-1, 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $new_filename = str_replace('__'.$previous_tail,"",$new_filename);
    }
    $new_filename = str_replace('.'.$fileinfos['extension'],"",$new_filename); // Deletes the extension
    $new_filename = $new_filename.'__'.$tail.'.'.$fileinfos['extension']; // Append our tail and the extension
    $new_filepath = 'myfiles/music/'.$new_filename; // Crea il nuovo percorso
    $i++;
}

copy('my_temp_directory/'.$new_depured_filename, $new_filepath); // Finally we copy the file to its destination directory

unlink('my_temp_directory/'.$new_depured_filename); // and delete the temporary one
```

Used functions:
[strtolower](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php)
[preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)
[copy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php)
[file_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)
[str_pad](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php)
[pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)
[str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)
[unlink](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php)

Answer (score 0):

To check if a file exists, you can use the [`file_exists`](http://fr.php.net/manual/fr/function.file-exists.php) function.

To cut the filename, you can use the [`pathinfo`](http://fr.php.net/manual/fr/function.pathinfo.php) function.

Comment: This likely covers my needs. I need to try it out and then I'll accept if it does.

Comment: Read all the responses before !
Leftnode and Cletus gave you some pretty advices here.

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
$file_name = time() . "_" . $uploaded_file_name;
```

Comment: i see what you're doing, and it'll work for 99.999% of the time, but given that time() "only" changes once per second, you could still hit conflicts. using a guid or at least microtime would be a more reliable prefix.

Comment: Yes,

$file_name = microtime() . "_" . $uploaded_file_name;

thanks nickf

Comment: Just a warning. For some bizarre reasons this does not work for me: $file_name = time() . "_" . $uploaded_file_name; move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$file_name"); update_post_meta($id, 'filename', $file_name); //This saves the filename in the database. There is SOMETIMES (not always) a discrepancy of 1 second between the actual filename and the saved filename. I really smell race condition here, but I can't pinpoint it other than the implementation of move_uploaded_file() itself.